# complicated query of orddr by and group by together on statement

Tags: mysql

I tried ORDER BY and GROUP BY together on statement, and ORDER by is not working; this is the code: `SELECT ter_code, ter_name, tgp_longitude, tgp_latitude FROM tblterminalgps, tblterminal WHERE ter_status != ? AND tgp_teruid = ter_uid GROUP BY ter_uid ORDER BY tgp_datecreated DESC`

On second try I tried this one: `SELECT t2.ter_code, t2.ter_name, t1.tgp_longitude, t1.tgp_latitude FROM tblterminalgps as t1 INNER JOIN tblterminal as t2 ON t1.tgp_teruid = t2.ter_uid

    (SELECT * FROM tblterminalgps GROUP BY t1.tgp_teruid DESC)
 ORDER BY tgp_datecreated DESC`

and I am getting this kind of error: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT * FROM tblterminalgps GROUP BY t1.tgp_teruid DESC)
 ORDER BY tgp_datecrea' at line 2`

Comment: 'ORDER by is not working' is too vague since you have not provided us with sample data and expected output

Comment: Please format your question properly. Also, Please see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: Please put sample data and output to make your problem clear